# Retrieve current value of List Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

How can I get the current value of a List in another Provider. That list is built with a changenotifier provider that uses a model that gets the data from a future provider. What I did before using riverpod was just pass the value through the pages using navigation. What's the best solution to use riverpod with this? Should I just set a toggleSelected? I was debating on implementing that but I do not know if it will be fast enough so it doesn't impact the navigation. That current value in the List influences the next page's results that I pass the data to.

```
Navigator.push(
         context,
         platformPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => JobPage(
                   listingInfo: job.id,
                 ),
             context: context),
       );
```

I used to just do that but now that isn't a viable solution

Comment: It would be helpful to provide code instead of trying to explain it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: share your code